# Is this solution correct for this problem about cauchy sequences?

Tags: calculus, cauchy-sequences

[image]

My first thought is that $x = a^{1/k}$, so of course $x$ is unique since $a^{1/k}$ is a specific fixed value. But this seemed way too simple of a solution so I think I am misunderstanding the problem.

I am also confused since this appeared in the exercises in a section about Cauchy sequences, but I don't see any relation to Cauchy sequences, whereas all the other problems were about proving something is a Cauchy sequence.

The picture is from the book: Advanced calculus of a single variable by Tunc Geveci, page 42.

Comment: How do you know that $ x  =a^{1/k}$ exists? This question is asking you to prove that it exists and is unique. So by claiming  that it exists, your argument becomes circular.

Comment: I hope one can construct a sequence using Newton Raphson on $f(x) =x^k-a$.

Comment: Do you have any hints to where to start in proving that $x = a^{1/k}$ exists? I first took it as basically a given that the $k$th root of a positive real number exists, but I am pretty lost on how to actually prove it.